# Looping FlipView for UWP

Tags: .net, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

Is there any way to make a FlipView loop through items? From the last item, to the first and viceversa. I have seen this solution http://blogs.msdn.com/b/synergist/archive/2013/09/21/windows-8-flipview-looping-sample.aspx

It works for W8, OK, but the same code throws under the Windows Universal Platform (Universal App).

Answer (score 2):

The solution you've mentioned is right, you can refer to this solution to implement your own.

But the sample linked in the article doesn't work because there is a minor mistake. In the *MainPage.xaml*, it use following code to use attached property

```
<FlipView x:Name="FlipView" Synergist:FlipViewExtensions.IsLooping="True">
```

But the namespace prefix "Synergist" is wrong, it should be "synergist" since it is defined as `xmlns:synergist="using:Synergist"`. So just change "Synergist" to "synergist":

```
<FlipView x:Name="FlipView" synergist:FlipViewExtensions.IsLooping="True">
```

The sample will work well.

And if you use these code in UWP, it will throw an exception at `flipView.ItemsSource = loopingList;`.

> WinRT information: Cannot complete a collection modification while another modification is in progress.
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Catastrophic failure
>
> Cannot complete a collection modification while another modification is in progress.
>
> - at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl.put_ItemsSource(Object value)
> - at Synergist.FlipViewExtensions.Initialize(FlipView flipView)

Although it's hard to say what's wrong here, we can set `IsLooping` attached property in code-behind after assigning or adding items to `FlipView.ItemsSource` to avoid this exception. For example:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var items = new Item[]
    {
        new Item { Name="1"},
        new Item { Name="2"},
        new Item { Name="3"},
        new Item { Name="4"},
        new Item { Name="5"},
        new Item { Name="6"},
        new Item { Name="7"},
        new Item { Name="8"},
        new Item { Name="9"},
        new Item { Name="10"},
    };

    var collection = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    this.FlipView.ItemsSource = collection;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        collection.Add(item);
    }

    Synergist.FlipViewExtensions.SetIsLooping(this.FlipView, true);
}
```

**Please check my Completed sample on [Github](https://github.com/Z-Jay/LoopingFlipViewUWP).**

Comment: OK that it works, but the workaround you propose for UWP is too brittle and it's not applicable for MVVM. Do you think it's a better way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to make FlipView be looping and keep good experience in UWP.

I implemented a CarouselView using compostion api to solve the problem. See it in [Github](https://github.com/pengzhxyz/CarouselView). The CarouselView have several features:

- supports infinite lopping.
- shows the neighbor images when the screen width is large.

It's easy to use just like the below code.

```
<carousel:CarouselView x:Name="carousel" ItemWidth="500"
          xmlns:carousel="using:CarouselView.Controls"/>
```

and then set the `ItemImageSource`(a `List<string>` dependency property) in code behind or **using Binding**

```
carousel.ItemImageSource = new List<string>()
{
    "https://img1.doubanio.com/view/photo/photo/public/p1204310498.jpg",
    "https://img1.doubanio.com/view/photo/photo/public/p1547743259.jpg",
    "https://img1.doubanio.com/view/photo/photo/public/p2183422782.jpg",
    "https://img1.doubanio.com/view/photo/photo/public/p832662844.jpg",
    "https://img1.doubanio.com/view/photo/photo/public/p752907403.jpg"
};
```

**You can view more details and check the sample in my [Github](https://github.com/pengzhxyz/CarouselView)**