# UWP Alarm and Clock app FlipView

Tags: uwp

I need to do a control like this one used in the Alarm and Clock app to display hours/minutes. So I tried to use a FlipView (in vertical mode) but I can't use a looping list.
Is there a more appropriate control to do it?

Comment: If you mean the control they use for selecting hours and minutes when editing alarm or timer, IMHO it's `TimePicker` with some styling.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1:

It is difficult to create a looping FlipView. You can use [Looping FlipView Attached Property](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Looping-FlipView-Attached-ab57350d). This is created for Windows 8 but it works fine with UWP.

**Sample Code**

*XAML Part*

```
<Page ....
      xmlns:synergist="using:Synergist">
<FlipView x:Name="flipView" synergist:FlipViewExtensions.IsLooping="True">
```

*Code Behind*

Setting `ItemsSource` may through an exception. Just put the code in a try catch block like the sample code below.

```
try
{
    flipView.ItemsSource = loopingList;
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

or set `ItemsSource` after adding the items to the `List`

- You can download the Attached Property from [Looping FlipView Attached Property](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Looping-FlipView-Attached-ab57350d)
- You can get more info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33665455/7331395)
- You can check the complete sample on Github: [LoopingFlipViewUWP](https://github.com/Z-Jay/LoopingFlipViewUWP/tree/master/LoopingFlipViewUWP)

### Method 2:

Create your own CustomPanel.

- You can get the complete guide from [LoopItemsPanel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mim/2013/04/16/winrt-create-a-custom-itemspanel-for-an-itemscontrol/)
- You can download the CustomPanel from [ItemsTemplatePanel.zip](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/10/41/15/61/ItemsTemplatePanel.zip)

### Method 3:

You can use the [Carousel Control](https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs#carousel) by AppStudio

- You can learn more from [Windows App Studio UWP Samples](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/windows-app-studio-uwp-samples/9nblggh4r0w1) app
- You can download the NuGet package from [WindowsAppStudio.Uwp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAppStudio.Uwp)

Comment: I already tried the "Method 1" but I changed the VirtualizingStackPanel Height property in the FlipView style and it seems it causes a problem when it appears.
I will look other methods

Comment: I can't do what I want with these methods. So, is there a way to set the FlipView item height?

Comment: @SamuelLIOULT What is the problem in setting FlipView item height?

Comment: The problem is when you scroll to bottom last items are cut. To reproduce this, change the orientation of the FlipView (by changing the VirtualizingStackPanel orientation in the base style) and add items in the FlipView (for example number from 0 to 24)

Comment: @SamuelLIOULT Can you give a link to sample repro?

Comment: I created a github repository with a sample here: https://github.com/SamuelLioult/FlipViewDemo

Comment: @SamuelLIOULT I will take a look. What kind of data do you want to display in this control?

Comment: Actually, I want to display simple types like int and string

Comment: @SamuelLIOULT Do you want to display hours/minutes or some other things?

Comment: For the moment I want to display hours/minutes/seconds (so the TimePicker can't do that I want) and enventually other features in the future